# how to drop multiple selected items in listView on Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a question. I am implementing small project on Qt c++. There is listview on mainwindow. I want to drop items in listview. I can drop one selected item. However I am trying to drop multiple selected items, listview drops only last selected item. How can I drop multiple seleceted items in Qt listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to do this:

```
QModelIndexList selectedRows = ui->listView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
```

Once you get what was selected you can iterate through `selectedRows` list to get the list of items you need to remove from the data you display.  Once the removal is done and the data is updated just `reset()` the model causing the view to refresh.

Comment: @user1117799 If this answer works for you you might want to accept it.  :)